# l2_hsic prevents my device from Deep Sleep. How to fix it?

Tags: kernel, wakelock

I have installed BetterBatteryStats and CPU SPY, because I noticed that I had a faster than normal battery consumption when the tab was left alone.

I made a 30 mins test Wifi OFF, Flight Mode On, where the 29 mins of them showed me l2_hsic under Kernel Wakelock -> Since Unplugged.

Does anyone know what causes this and how to prevent it ?

Thank you.

( I am running Stock ICS 4.0.4 rooted)

Comment: Do you have a Galaxy Note?

Comment: @Flow No, I am having Samsung Tab 10.1

Comment: It's a [known problem on the Galaxy Note](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1656705). But a quick google search showed no solution.

Comment: @Flow So I guess we payed for flawed devices ?

Comment: God forbid if I ever buy a Samsung smartphone again. I only own a Galaxy S and they didn't care to release ICS for it. I have no Samsung Tab or Galaxy Note.

Comment: Try flashing the radio firmware? See this [XDA posting](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=26959743&postcount=83) And also this pertinent thread about it on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1656705&page=9)

Comment: @Flow: Is there currently a manufacturer that regularly updates ~16 month old phones (the time difference between the Galaxy S release and the release of ICS)?

Comment: Maybe not. But it's not only their update policy. There are a few more things that made my Samsung  Smartphone experience miserable. Fell free to ping me in chat if you want more info.

Answer (score 1):

As Flow already pointed out in his comment to the question, that is a known bug. However, if you're affected, there's at least a kind of "ugly work-around", as described in the article [How to solve battery issues after ICS update in your Galaxy Note](http://www.allaboutgalaxynote.com/how-to-solve-battery-issues-after-ics-update-in-your-galaxy-note/). Their conclusion states:

> Anyway, this is a kernel bug in ICS, we have to wait for new update. The solution for this is: **shutdown your Note, peel off the back cover, remove the battery; hold the battery for more than one min, put the battery back, put back the back cover; start the phone.** Then, everything goes back to normal. **Reboot your phone will NOT solver this issue, at least for me.**
>   Next time, when you encounter this issue again, try the procedure again.

They further write that, if you once encountered this bug and worked-around this way, *it seems it is hard to hit the bug again* -- so with some luck, you will only have to do this once.

And yes, I saw that article refers to the Galaxy Note. But talking about a *kernel bug in ICS*, and your tablet being from the same manufacturer, chances are pretty good this solution will apply to your tablet as well.

Comment: Just to add, newer versions of CM10-based ROMs don't seem to have this problem (it went away for me at least).