# Why does Better Battery Stats say my Galaxy S4 is awake 100% of the time?

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I think the screenshots speak for themselves. Can't pinpoint a reason from what I see. Anyone can help please? Thanks

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3] [image: Screenshot 4]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Buggy Samsung firmware. Just search for "l2_hsic wakelock".

Comment: @ce4 thank you. What can we do about it?

Comment: Not quite sure, what could help. XDA's thread (for the Galaxy S2) is full of posts and there's only little real information. Maybe follow some suggestions mentioned here (and in the linked thread): http://www.xda-developers.com/android/att-galaxy-s2-owners-can-now-identify-whats-eating-their-battery/

Comment: Here's another article about an app that tries to detect the culprit: http://www.xda-developers.com/android/defend-your-battery-with-wakelock-detector/

Comment: AFAIK the `l2_hsic` wakelock is connected to "Fast Dormancy". Might be your modem has some trouble with it, as described in some XDA threads (e.g. [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2149003)). Also see: [kernel - l2_hsic prevents my device from Deep Sleep. How to fix it](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28055/16575). Both links are about a Galaxy Note, but the underlying issue might be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buggy firmware. Restarted and problem went away.